# Comments between dictionary initialization lines in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have a multiline statement in VB.NET and I'd like to put comments in between the lines to help clarify some stuff.

Essentially, I'd like a comment to look something like this:

```
            New PropertyThingy() From {
                {"reallyLongDictionaryKeyNameThatIsExcessivelyLong", data.reallyLongPropertyName},
                {"theApiMaintainerReallyLikesVerboseKeys", data.Blagh},
                ' I'd like to put a line here...
                {"whyAreTheseReallyVerbose", data.SomeProperty},
            }
```

Unfortunately, I can't get it to compile because of this error: "Syntax Error: Collection element initializer expected." Is there a way to get comments between the lines?

I've also tried this:

```
            New PropertyThingy() From {
                {"reallyLongDictionaryKeyNameThatIsExcessivelyLong", data.reallyLongPropertyName},
                {"theApiMaintainerReallyLikesVerboseKeys", data.Blagh},
                _ ' Some comment goes here:
                {"whyAreTheseReallyVerbose", data.SomeProperty},
            }
```

Comment: Can you explain why you need the underscore here? This seems the initialization of some sort of collection (a Dictionary ?) then you don't need the underscore. Could you post the code that uses these lines?

Comment: Not enough context. Where is the rest of the code that goes with these lines? What are you initializing here?

Comment: I've updated the question. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems the code that initialize a Dictionary. Then you don't need the underscore, but you still can't have the comment between the lines.

However you could write the comment on the same line

```
Dim c = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)() From
{
    {"abc", 1}, ' Description of the first entry
    {"def", 2}  ' Description of the second entry
}
```

Comment: ISTR that comment-on-the-same-line is a feature added in VS2015.

Comment: @AndrewMorton yes you are correct https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/we86c8x2.aspx

Comment: OK another hint that the _between lines_ is not supported here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vbteam/2014/12/09/new-language-features-in-visual-basic-14/